# React iframe youtube : Object.defineProperty called on non-object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, youtube

I made a component to embed a youtube video in my React app and it works great.

To do that i'm using an iframe.

```
 <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe className="embed-responsive-item" src={`${BASE_URL}${videoId}`}/>
 </div>
```

**But even if it works,** I don't know why but I got this error.

> **sw.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object**

This seems to be a youtube issue because if I use another URL in my iframe 
than : https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZJD1zoAaCmo
like for example :  https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xwr14q

I'll not have the error anymore

If you have any idea it would be really appreciated

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Having the same issue in Angular 4. Here is my embed code: <ion-item *ngIf="(sidenav$ | async) && ((sidenav$ | async)?.tutorialVideo)">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="560" height="315" [src]="(sidenav$ | async)?.tutorialVideo | youtube" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </ion-item>

Answer (score 0):

You should use class instead of className in your html.

Yes, it is true you refer to those as className on js code, but the reserved word is class in html.

Javascript does not recognize className like that in all situations, so thus the error.

Edit: actually, className is for React and class is for normal html. This code uses features of Bootstrap and it uses html markups.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue.  We're seeing this issue (new today) too, and we don't use className or React.

Comment: Agreed, it's new. Only occurs on localhost for us. Occurs when pausing video. After a minute console displays: "Service Worker termination by a timeout timer was canceled because DevTools is attached."

Comment: Well ok so that is kind of reconforting to know that this is not an error coming from the code. Definitely coming from Youtube if even using an other langage we got this error